# Union all data unmanaged

Tags: sql, postgresql

Forgive me if this question already ask,not much of db guy here ,
here is what i tried,

```
select row_number() over (partition by name order by challanto_date) , * 
from (
    select
        rma,
        p.id,
        p.name,
        challanto_date,
        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as fromDate
    from challan_to_vendor cv
    left join challan_to_vendor_detail cvd on cv.id = cvd.challan_to_vendor_id 
    inner join main_product p on p.id = cvd.product_id
    union all
    select 
        rma, 
        p.id, 
        p.name, 
        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as toDate, 
        challan_date
    from challan_from_vendor cv
    left join challan_from_vendor_detail cvd on cv.id = cvd.challan_from_vendor_id
    inner join main_product p on p.id = cvd.product_id
) as a
```

Here is my create table script :

challan_from_vendor

```
  CREATE TABLE public.challan_from_vendor
  (
  id character varying NOT NULL,
  date_ad date,
  rma integer DEFAULT 1,
  CONSTRAINT psk PRIMARY KEY (id)
  )
```

challan_from_vendor_detail

```
CREATE TABLE public.challan_from_vendor_detail
 (
 id character varying NOT NULL,
 challan_from_id character varying,
 product_id character varying,
 CONSTRAINT psks PRIMARY KEY (id),
 CONSTRAINT fsks FOREIGN KEY (challan_from_id)
     REFERENCES public.challan_from_vendor (id) MATCH SIMPLE
     ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
 )
```

challan_to_vendor;

```
CREATE TABLE public.challan_to_vendor
(
 id character varying NOT NULL,
 date_ad date,
 rma integer DEFAULT 1,
 CONSTRAINT pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

challan_to_vendor_detail

```
CREATE TABLE public.challan_to_vendor_detail
 (
 id character varying NOT NULL,
 challan_to_id character varying,
 product_id character varying,
 CONSTRAINT pks PRIMARY KEY (id),
 CONSTRAINT fks FOREIGN KEY (challan_to_id)
    REFERENCES public.challan_to_vendor (id) MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
 )
```

product

```
    CREATE TABLE public.product
 (
 id character varying NOT NULL,
 product_name character varying,
 CONSTRAINT pks PRIMARY KEY (id)
 )
```

Here is my table structures and desire output.

challan_from_vendor

```
| id       | rma | date |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|
| 12012       |        0001 |     2018-11-10    
| 123121       |        0001 |     2018-11-11
```

challan_to_vendor

```
| id       | rma | date |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|
| 12       |        0001 |     2018-12-10    
| 123       |        0001 |     2018-12-11
```

challan_from_vendor_detail

```
 | id       | challan_from_vendor_id | product_id |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|
| 121       |  12012       | 121313        
| 1213       |   12012     |  131381
```

challan_to_vendor_detail

```
challan_from_vendor_detail

| id         | challan_to_vendor_id | product_id |
|:-----------|------------------------|:------------:|
| 121        |  12                    | 121313        
| 1213       |   123                  |  131381
```

product

```
  | id         | product_name | 
|:-----------|------------:|
| 191313       |    apple   |
| 89113       |      banana |
```

Output

```
| ram         | product_id | challan_from_date | challan_to_date|
|:-----------|------------:|:-----------------:|:--------------:|
| 0001       |       191313|     2018-11-10    |2018-11-11      |     
| 0001       |       89113 |     2018-12-10    |2018-12-11      |
```

Comment: If they're supposed to be in the same row, then you probably want `GROUP BY`?

Comment: ya but it force me to also group by other column so , thats make differences

Comment: Please show us your expected output.  Your question is not clear.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, here i am joining two table which have same product i want 1st date from A table and 2nd date from B table. two date are related , suppose you send a product in 1st date which is in table A , you alse receive same product in 2nd date which is in table B

Comment: I have updated the question , hope this helps , thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is some strange things in the query you have tried so it is not clear what tables, how they are related or what the columns are in those tables.

So by some guessing I give you this to start of with:

```
select
    main_product.*,
    challan_to_vendor.toDate,
    challan_from_vendor.fromDate
from main_product
join challan_to_vendor using(product_id)
join challan_from_vendor using(product_id)
```

If you explain more about your db an what you want out of it I might be able to help you more.

---

**Edit**: So I could not run your create statements in my db since there was naming conflicts among other minor things. Here is some advice on the create process that I find useful:

- Let the id's be `integer` instead of `character varying` otherwise it is probably a name-column and should not be named `id`. You also used integer-id's in your examples.
- Use `SERIAL PRIMARY KEY` ([see tutorial](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-serial/)) to help you with the key creation. This also removes the naming-conflict since the constraints are given implicit unique names.
- Use the same column-name for the same thing in all places to avoid confusion by having multiple things called `id` after a join plus that it simplify's the join. So for example the `id` of the product should be `product_id` in all places, that way you could use `using(product_id)` as your join condition.

So with the advises given above here's how I would create one of your table and then query them:

```
CREATE TABLE public.challan_to_vendor_detail
(
    challan_to_vendor_detail_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    challan_to_vendor_id integer,
    product_id integer,
    CONSTRAINT fks FOREIGN KEY (challan_to_vendor_id)
    REFERENCES public.challan_to_vendor (challan_to_vendor_id) MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
);

select
    product_name,
    challan_to_vendor.date_ad as date_to,
    challan_from_vendor.date_ad as date_from
from product
join challan_to_vendor_detail using(product_id)
join challan_to_vendor using(challan_to_vendor_id)
join challan_from_vendor_detail using(product_id)
join challan_from_vendor using(challan_from_vendor_id)
```

Unfortunately the overall db-design does not make sense to me so I do not know if this is what you expect.

Good luck!